# Inserting data from one matrix to another matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have an empty matrix (5000 x 200) with User.IDs as rows and movie names as the column names. Currently every cell in the matrix has an NA.

Now I have a "training matrix" - basically a sample of the dataset used for training, in matrix format. The training matrix has dimensions of 3500 x 200, but with some values filled in for the ratings that users gave particular users.

Now what I'm trying to is "overlay" or "insert" the training matrix into the empty matrix. In effect, where a user has rated a movie, I'd like that inserted into the empty matrix, but keeping the dimensions of the empty matrix. Essentially match up the "User ID" row with the "movie name" column where applicable. Someone has referred me to the `complete` function from the `dplyr` package but I'm not exactly sure how I would implement such a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, suppose you have a training matrix with (true) rownames:

```
m <- rbind(c(10,8,2),
           c(9,8,7),
           c(10,6,5))
rownames(m) <- c("Bob", "Denise", "Ernie")
```

where:

```
> class(m)
[1] "matrix"
> m
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
Bob      10    8    2
Denise    9    8    7
Ernie    10    6    5
>
```

and a larger empty output matrix:

```
e <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow=5, ncol=3)
rownames(e) <- c("Alice", "Bob", "Carla", "Denise", "Ernie")
```

where:

```
> e
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
Alice    NA   NA   NA
Bob      NA   NA   NA
Carla    NA   NA   NA
Denise   NA   NA   NA
Ernie    NA   NA   NA
>
```

In this case, you can use the `match()` function to generate a vector of the row indexes in the empty output matrix that match the rows in the input matrix:

```
o <- match(rownames(m), rownames(e))
if (any(is.na(o))) stop("oops -- didn't match everyone")
```

giving:

```
> o
[1] 2 4 5
>
```

and then after:

```
e[o,] <- m
```

the output matrix will have the desired contents:

```
> e
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
Alice    NA   NA   NA
Bob      10    8    2
Carla    NA   NA   NA
Denise    9    8    7
Ernie    10    6    5
>
```